# How `window.wp.oldEditor` is being set in the editor?

Tags: block-editor, editor

I'm trying to implement WordPress Gutenberg editor outside of WordPress itself. Everything is working fine except having old classic block support and that requires `window.wp.oldEditor` to be set.

If you take a look at devtools console on post editing pages, `window.wp.oldEditor` is initiated with this:
[image]

How can I initiate this variable by myself, out of the WordPress environment?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ... Got it. It's not related to Gutenberg editor but WordPress core itself:

`window.wp.editor` is being initiated here with those methods:
https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/9ed92faaca92f66ec9e2979c9d896ddab3e4e993/src/js/_enqueues/wp/editor/base.js

And then, `window.wp.oldEditor = window.wp.editor`:
https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5868743f1f2b05c93642c9eebf89cb7f6610d6df/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L369